# Не получается корректно анимировать navbar при скролле (position: fixed)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, анимация

Идея в том, чтобы **при прокрутке страницы *НИЖЕ* высоты окна браузера, nav-меню плавно выезжало сверху и фиксировалось. И наоборот, при прокрутке *ВЫШЕ* высоты окна браузера, nav-меню плавно уезжало вверх**.
Выезжает вниз-то оно нормально, а вот вверх улетает без анимации и вообще не понимаю как все реализовать корректно.
Взял простенькую реализацию navbar с bootstrap для примера. вот весь код:

css

```
<style>
    body{
        min-height: 2000px;
    }
    .fix{
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        animation: anim 1s forwards;
    }
    @keyframes anim{
        0%{
            transform: translateY(-100%);
        }
        100%{
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
</style>
```

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form class="d-flex">
         <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

js (jquery)

```
<script>
    var wHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (offset > wHeight) {
            $('nav').addClass('fix');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('fix');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Пробовал в блоке else помимо удаления fix, добавлять класс например endAnim, который делал бы противоположную анимацию. Но бесполезно, так как fix удаляется, nav мгновенно улетает вверх.
Весь день вот сижу играюсь с этой анимацией и все не получается никак реализовать.   Погуглил, тоже ничего подходящего не нашел.
Как же все-таки реализовать эту, казалось бы, простую задачу???
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам здесь не нужно правило `@keyframes`, оно лишнее.

Причина, почему у вас так получается, очевидная. Когда вы удаляете класс `fix`, то значение у свойства `position` меняется с `fixed` на `relative`. Поэтому у вас элемент и "улетает", то есть возвращается на своё исходное место.

```js
var wHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (offset > wHeight) {
    $('nav').addClass('fix');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fix');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.fix {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

upd/

```js
var wHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (offset > wHeight) {
    $('nav').addClass('fix');
    $('nav').removeClass('no_fix');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fix');
    $('nav').addClass('no_fix');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.fix {
  position: fixed;
  animation: fix 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fix {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.no_fix {
  position: relative;
  animation: no_fix 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes no_fix {
  0% {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  90% {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  100% {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Работает как надо, но теперь при загрузке страницы, не видно само меню из-за дефолтного значения transform: translateY(-200%); у nav

Comment: ` , Да, именно. пробую сейчас пофиксить это исходя из вашего примера, пока переменные успехи)) балин

Comment: ` , переписал все свойства из nav в класс .navvv и дописал пару условий в js:  
var navHeight = $('nav').innerHeight();
   if (offset > navHeight) {
    $('nav').addClass('navvv');
   } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('navvv');
   } // Вроде работает, но прыгает как-то странно при первом скролле

Comment: Да, как раз то, что нужно было! Наверное так бы и не допер без вашей помощи)) Спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли!!!)